# Exactly what does handleData do in a reactjs script?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaderboard

I have made it [this far](https://codepen.io/profaneVoodoo/pen/GqbpQj) with a FreeCodeCamp project, with a bit of help from some folks who have traveled further down the react.js road. 
Before I go on, though, can someone please explain to me exactly what "this.handleData" accomplishes in the following code? (It is someone else's code I was allowed to use, and it helps me get the data I am grabbing from the api to render on the page, but what exactly is handleData doing?)

```
var LeaderList = React.createClass({  
    render:function(){
    return(
      <div >
    <h1>Here is the data...</h1>
    <AllData />
    </div>
    );
  }
});

var AllData = React.createClass({

    dataUrl: 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent',
    getInitialState: function() { 
        return {data: []}
    },
    componentDidMount: function(){
        $.getJSON(this.dataUrl, this.handleData)
    },
    handleData: function(data){
        this.setState({data: data});
    },

    render: function(){
        var elems = [];
        for(var i=0; i<this.state.data.length; i++){
          var subelems = [];
          subelems.push(<div><p>{this.state.data[i].img}</p></div>);
          subelems.push(<div><p>{this.state.data[i].username}</p></div>);
          subelems.push(<div><p>{this.state.data[i].recent}</p></div>);
          subelems.push(<div><p>{this.state.data[i].alltime}</p></div>);
          elems.push(subelems);
        }
        return (<div>{elems}</div>);
    }

});

ReactDOM.render(
  <LeaderList />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In that code `handleData` is a custom method that calls `setState`. [setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.htm) is part of the React Component API. It causes the Component to re-render, using the data passed to it to set the `this.state` property available to the component. `this.state` is accessible in the `render` method, so the `data` passed to `handleData` is being made available to the `render` method.

As you can see in the `render` method, `this.state` is accessed to control what DOM is created.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `componentDidMount()` makes a call to your component's `dataUrl`, and gets back some data. `handleData` takes that data and uses it to set the component's state, or internal data store.

That's then used below in the component's `render()` function, which gets called whenever the state changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the place to start here is the `componentDidMount` function. If you take a look at the React Component Lifecycle, you'll see that this function is called after the initial render when the component is placed into the DOM: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

The docs advise that:

> If you want to integrate with other JavaScript frameworks, set timers
>   using setTimeout or setInterval, or send AJAX requests, perform those
>   operations in this method.

It looks like we're making an Ajax call here (Via what I assume is JQuery) to fetch some data from the server. We pass in `handleData` as a callback which will be called with the results once the Ajax request is complete, which does this:

`this.setState({data: data});`

To understand what `state` is in React there are a couple of good links here:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html

> State is reserved only for interactivity, that is, data that changes over time

This is applicable to us as the result of the Ajax request will change this data - only once from nothing to something, but it still changes. When you call `setState` React triggers a "state transition" which will eventually call `render` again, where it will populate the `elems` variable with your data and display it on the screen.